# blogdown::new_site() fails: Error in site_root(config)

Tags: r, rstudio, hugo, blogdown

I want to create a site using `blogdown`.

Following instructions in the **1.2 A quick example** of [blogdown eBook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/a-quick-example.html), of `blogdown`, I created a new project based on new directory then got the error below.

I just installed `Hugo` and `blogdown` so I guess it's not about the package version. I tried to look for information about the error message, and noticed that there are several questions related to `blogdown::new_site()`. I checked those but it seems like my problem is different. Hope that it won't be a bad question to ask. Please check the information below.

```
blogdown::new_site()
```

Then I got messages:

> Congratulations! Your new Hugo site is created in D:\R_programming\t2.
>
> Just a few more steps and you're ready to go:
>
> 1. Download a theme into the same-named folder.    Choose a theme from https://themes.gohugo.io/, or    create your own with the "hugo new
>      theme " command.
> 2. Perhaps you want to add some content. You can add single files    with "hugo new \.".
> 3. Start the built-in live server via "hugo server".
>
> Visit https://gohugo.io/ for quickstart guide and full documentation.
>   trying URL 'https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium/archive/master.zip'
>   downloaded 115 KB

Then here comes the error message.

> Error in site_root(config) :  Cannot find a website under the current
>   working directory or upper-level directories

This is a copy of my `sessionInfo()`

> ```
> sessionInfo()
>
> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:  [1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950  [2]
> LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950    [3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese
> (Traditional)_Taiwan.950 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                             
> [5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950    
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
> datasets  methods   base     
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_3.5.1   
> assertthat_0.2.0  bookdown_0.8      cli_1.0.1         [5] tools_3.5.1 
> withr_2.1.2       rstudioapi_0.8    yaml_2.2.0        [9] crayon_1.3.4
> blogdown_0.9      knitr_1.21        xfun_0.4          [13]
> sessioninfo_1.1.1
> ```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with the current latest version of Hugo on Windows. What is your `blogdown::hugo_version()`? Is there a `config.toml` under that directory (it should be automatically generated by `blogdown::new_site()`)?

Comment: @YihuiXie Thanks or your reply. The version is `[1] ‘0.52’`.

Comment: And yes, there is a config.toml under the directory generated by `blogdown::new_site()`. I am not sure whether it is important or not, but `blogdown::new_site()` generated three files, which are **content**, **static**, and **themes**, and a **Rproj**, a **config.toml**, and an **index.Rmd**. I read your book and there should be a fill named **public**? Hope the information helps. Thanks again.

Comment: `public` will be automatically generated if the website can be rendered successfully. What does `blogdown:::site_root()` return? An error too?

Comment: @YihuiXie sorry for the late reply.
`> blogdown:::site_root()`
`[1] "D:/R_programming/t2"`
And yes, I don't have the public file after rendering.

Comment: This is weird. I still cannot reproduce your problem. So `blogdown::serve_site()` will trigger the error on your computer? If you know how to debug R functions, you may investigate it by yourself: clone the package from Github, add `browser()` before this line https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/master/R/serve.R#L51, install the modified package, and check the values of `getwd(); list.files()` after you run `blogdown::serve_site()`.

Comment: Or actually just restart your R session, run `remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')`, then `blogdown::serve_site()`, and let me know the error message.